# ObjectMapper - initialize object IOS

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, swift2

Simple thing that is giving me a headache - how to initialize an object that conforms to mappable protocol, without any JSON yet.

What I would like to do, is simply initialise empty User object in code like this:

```
let user = User()
```

however that gives me error:
"missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

I was able to do it in version 0.14 with swift 1.2, but now it doesnt work. Do you guys know how to do it now in swift 2 and new Object Mapper ? (I know how to initialize it with json etc, I just want to initialize that object for other purposes and I cant figure out how)

```
class User: Mappable {
var username: String?
var age: Int?
var weight: Double!
var array: [AnyObject]?
var dictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
var bestFriend: User?                       // Nested User object
var friends: [User]?                        // Array of Users
var birthday: NSDate?

required init?(_ map: Map) {

}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    username    <- map["username"]
    age         <- map["age"]
    weight      <- map["weight"]
    array       <- map["arr"]
    dictionary  <- map["dict"]
    bestFriend  <- map["best_friend"]
    friends     <- map["friends"]
    birthday    <- (map["birthday"], DateTransform())
}
}
```

please help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following should work:

```
class User: NSObject, Mappable {
var username: String?
var age: Int?
var weight: Double!
var array: [AnyObject]?
var dictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
var bestFriend: User?                       // Nested User object
var friends: [User]?                        // Array of Users
var birthday: NSDate?

override init() {
    super.init()
}

convenience required init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    username    <- map["username"]
    age         <- map["age"]
    weight      <- map["weight"]
    array       <- map["arr"]
    dictionary  <- map["dict"]
    bestFriend  <- map["best_friend"]
    friends     <- map["friends"]
    birthday    <- (map["birthday"], DateTransform())
}
}
```

Comment: 2 errors: on override init() "Initilaizer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass", next error on self.init() -> "Value of type '_ -> _" has no member ''init"

Comment: I don't have such errors. pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 1.0'; Swift 2.1. You can try to remove override init() { super.init() }.

Comment: @SergeyDemchenko I got the same error as Ammo and removing override init() defeats the purpose. ObjectMapper 1.2 Swift 2.2

Answer (score 11):

Fixed version of above answer:

```
init() {}
required convenience init?(_ map: Map) { self.init() }
```